# How to play action actuator logic brick via python

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I want to know how to play(send true pulse) to an action actuator via script (logic brick with all the settings) since playAction doesn't have animation property which I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use python to activate the *Action* actuator with this script. You will need three logic bricks: A sensor (to trigger it all), the python controller, and the action actuator.
[image: logic bricks]

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

act = cont.actuators["Action"] # the name of the Action actuator

if cont.sensors["Keyboard"].positive: # trigger when buton pressed

    #Set all the properties you want
    act.action = "CubeAction"
    act.frameStart = 1
    act.frameEnd = 30
    act.priority = 0

    cont.activate(act) # start the actuator
```

You can set as many or as few of the settings that you need with python or in the logic brick, however the python will overrule any duplicate settings. [Here](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bge.types.BL_ActionActuator.html) is a list of all the settings for the Action actuator.
Do note the the two minimum setting you need are the action name, and frame end.

Comment: c.activate(act) was the only thing what i needed but thx for all

Comment: Your code refers to the sensor and actuator explicitly by name. Could they be looked up by the "in" and "out" connectors of the controller brick?

Comment: @Passiday no, you have to specify the logic bricks by name, or id.